# Изменить EditText фрагмента из адаптера recyclerview

Tags: android

Во фрагменте создан EditText, в recyclerview тоже, я пытаюсь их синхронизировать, но не пойму как это правильно сделать. Данные для адаптера содержатся в editModelArrayList. Во фрагменте создал:

```
  public void setEditid() {
  editid.setText(editModelArrayList.get(0).getEditTextValue());
}
```

В адаптере:

```
FragmentC per = new FragmentC();
per.setEditid();
```

Получаю

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с этим работать.

Comment: вы создаете новый фрагмент, который никуда не "подключен" и пытаетесь чтобы он что то делал? для связи между адаптером и фрагментом исользуйте методы обратного вызова

Comment: Спасибо что подсказали куда копать, решил наконец-то